# Atom Electron cant find path of child process?

Tags: node.js, electron

I built an app with electron and in the root directory I have a library. I want to run a child process from my app, so I use it like this:

```
spawn(path.resolve(LIB_PATH +'command_to_run')
```

This works when I run the app with `npm start`. But if I use electron-packager to make a build, it seems that it doesn't find the command. I receive this error: [image]

Any ideas why this happens? I was researching a lot about it, but can't find anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. When I run `npm start` I can directly call `./command_to_run` from the root of my project. But when I create a .app file, I need to add this: `path.dirname(require.main.filename) + 'command_to_run'`. Then it'll call the file that is in the root of my directory.